# Vim: vmap substitute required an extra escape

Tags: regex, vim

I'm rather new to Vim's `map` command, but I understand the general syntax.

TL:DR: 
Why do I need the extra pipe in my ~/.vimrc file?

```
vmap <C-e> :s/^\(\/\*\\| \*\/\\| \*\)/\/\/\//g<CR>:noh<CR>
```

BACKGROUND: I'm confused on a map I wrote to have `<C-e>` replace

```
/*
 * Comment blocks
 */
```

with

```
///
/// Company Doxygen comment block
///
```

If I write the substitute in the vim command-line, it works fine without the extra `\` on the `|` operator.

`:'<,'>s/^\(\/\*\| \*\/\| \*\)/\/\/\//g<CR>:noh<CR>`

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pipe, `|`, is used to separate Vim commands. So if you did the following:

```
map a b | c
```

It would be read as two different commands/statements: `map a b` and `c`. In order to avoid `|` being interrupted as a command separator you need to escape it via `\|` or use `<bar>`.

So your command will look more like the following:

```
xnoremap <c-e> :s#\v^(/\*<bar> \*/<bar> \*)#///#g<CR>:noh<CR>
```

Note: I have reduced the escaping by using `#` as the substitute delimiter as well as using very magic, `\v`. I also switched to `noremap` to prevent remapping as well as use `xmap` instead of `vmap` to prevent this from being triggered in select mode.

For more help see:

```
:h :|
:h <bar>
:h key-codes
:h :map-commands
:h /\v
```

Comment: Thank you, I was not aware of that. I shall accept this as soon as possible.